# machine learning+deep learning+speech recognition

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, speech-recognition, ctc

I run the code in my editor (VS Code) without any problems, but for next step and due to RAM and GPU limitation, I took it in colab, but got an error that seems to be due to mismatch of versions due to transfer from my editor to colab. how can i fix  this problem?

The current version of python running on Google Colab is 3.8.16, I used tensorflow 2.3.0 and keras 2.4.3.

The error is related to this part of code when use the `model.fit()` for train the model:

(I use CTC_loss in model):

```py
model.fit(
    train_dg,
    validation_data=val_dg,
    epochs=args.epochs,
    callbacks=[PlotLossesKeras(),
        early_stopping,
        cp,
        csv_logger,
        lrs]
)
```

But I got this error:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Epoch 00001: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to 0.001. Epoch 1/300
-----------**---------------------------------------------------------------- InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-87-2b4ea6811b43> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(train_dg,validation_data=val_dg,epochs=args.epochs,callbacks=[PlotLossesKeras(),early_stopping,cp,csv_logger,lrs])

9 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError:  Saw a non-null label (index >= num_classes - 1) following a null label, batch: 2 num_classes: 16 labels: 16,0,0,0,0,0,0 labels seen so far:       [[node functional_3/CTCloss/CTCLoss (defined at <ipython-input-17-1689d20fc46d>:887) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_6401]

Function call stack: train_function 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I try change the version of python in colab but it dosent work.
also change num_classes in the last layer of my model, it dosent work too.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data. As the error mentions, there seems to be inconsistencies in the data. Your `num_classes` are 16, which assumes the classes to be [0,…,15]. But, one of the label lies out of this range.